# How to add more than one horizontal line? One solid and one dashed?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p + geom_hline(yintercept=5.17, col="red")
p + geom_hline(yintercept=20.69, linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

I used these two codes, but the bottom one cancels the top one.
Thank you

Comment: you were almost there. What @Axeman shows in his answer - you just need to add the plot to the previous plot. Don't forget to assign your new plot to a new object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of of these:

```
p + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=5.17, col="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=20.69, linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

Or

```
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=5.17, col="red")
p + geom_hline(yintercept=20.69, linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

Or

```
p + geom_hline(yintercept = c(5.17, 20.69), col = "red", linetype = c('solid', 'dashed'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot. And do you know how can i put this lines in the legend of the graph?